# Login on a website with python, I tried many examples, but what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, cookies, authentication, python-requests

I know there have been plenty of examples on here that explain how to login on a website with Python, but I've been trying for the past 3 days and I didn't manage to get anything to work.
This might be due to the fact Python is completely new to me, so please, pardon my ignorance.

The way that attracts me most is by using **requests**, as it seems to be the shortest way.

*I made a test account on this website so you guys could test your own stuff if you'd like*:

```
import requests

# variables
login_url = 'http://www.helifreak.com/'
username = 'testsubject'
password = 'password123'
login_data = {'vb_login_username' : username, 'vb_login_password' : password}


# making headers to look like a web browser
hf_headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36'}

# creation of the session and login
s = requests.Session()
login = s.post(login_url, data=login_data, headers=hf_headers)

# printing the output to check if the login worked
print login.content
```

It seems that with this example, the content that prints out shows I am not logged in.

I feel a little bad asking this, considering the amount of examples there are out there that should help me out, but this has really been driving me crazy, I simply don't see why it's not working.

The only thing I could think of is, my login_data defines the 'name' of the input, while I've seen several people use the 'id' of that input. Though, my page doesn't seem to have an 'id' for password or username inputs, and I have also read on here using the 'name' is fine.

Conclusion: I'm confused.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The action attribute for the login form is `login.php?do=login` so it doesn't seem like you are posting to the right URL.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, how did you find this?

Comment: Using chrome dev tools. Once I find the login form, I inspected it and checked what the attribute was. That URL is the URL the firm sends the data to so that is literally the URL you wasn't to post to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the source of the HTML that you've provided, I've realized that the URL that you should post to is:

```
http://www.helifreak.com/login.php
```

Second thing that you need to do is to figure out what md5hash function is doing and do the same in your Python program before you POST.

I've just found md5hash function's location. It's defined here: http://www.helifreak.com/clientscript/vbulletin_md5.js. What they do there is hashing form fields using MD5 algorithm and then assign the hash to the field's values. You'll need to do the same in Python if you want to login successfully.

Here is a solution. It was simpler than I thought, but you would need to use mechanize (sudo pip install mechanize), because there are many hidden fields that you would need to fill out if you use 'requests':

```
>>> import md5
>>> import mechanize
>>> br = mechanize.Browser()
>>> r=br.open("http://www.helifreak.com")
>>> for f in br.forms():
...     if (f.action == 'http://www.helifreak.com/login.php'):
...             ff=f
... 
>>> m=md5.new()
>>> m.update('password123')
>>> d=m.hexdigest()
>>> ff.set_all_readonly(False)
>>> ff.set_value(d,'vb_login_md5password')
>>> ff.set_value(d,'vb_login_md5password_utf')
>>> ff.set_value('testsubject','vb_login_username')
>>> br.form=ff
>>> r=br.submit()
>>> print r.read()
```

The last printed response indicated that the login was successful.

Comment: Thank you very much for this insight. So what you're saying is I have to hash the login_data (using hashlib for example) and post the values that way?

Comment: You need to open that javascript function and see what they are doing exactly for the call: md5hash(vb_login_password, vb_login_md5password, vb_login_md5password_utf,0). After analyzing *md5.js script a bit, I've realized that they take pwd from vb_login_password and store its MD5 to fields vb_login_md5password and vb_login_md5password_utf. I might try to write an equivalent Python code if time permits, but you can try to do it yourself as well.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late, and thanks for this working response!